# Can someone tell me how to achieve this effect?

Tags: css, html

I'm looking to achieve the same image effect on this site

http://gilgul.co.il/

Can someone point me towards the type of css technology or explain how the images move? I'm assuming it's similar to gifs?

Comment: this is a great question, Im not sure why people are downvoting it. Im actually curious to know how they achieved it too... +1!

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone point me towards the type of css technology or explain how the images move? I'm assuming it's similar to gifs?

It's so similar to a gif, that it is achieved with a gif.

http://d1fki99wqld33s.cloudfront.net/assets/gifs/GIF25s.gif
http://d1fki99wqld33s.cloudfront.net/assets/gifs/GIF8s.gif

So they put an element that spans the full width with the gif set as the background image, set to span the whole width. Then they nest another element inside of that element with this [semi transparent PNG](http://d1fki99wqld33s.cloudfront.net/assets/net.png) tiled to create the netting effect.

They also have some crazy javascript to respond to scroll position and manage what images are pinned where to keep it all looking nice.

The end result is pretty slick, but it takes a decent amount of plumbing. There isn't a single "trick" that does this. Just a stack of clever things. Any one of which could be multiple Stack Overflow questions each.

---

Oh and FYI, that page is 14.5MB to fully load. That's pretty gigantic. That can have some performance consequences on slower, or capped bandwidth, internet connections.

Comment: if you look on the website... there is a div called .net that has a constant div class being added then removed. I'm not finding jquery that is doing this though.

Comment: actually.. i found the script, but I have no clue what its point is. it doesnt do anything. lol

Comment: I noticed that `.net` class toggling too, but I have no idea why it's doing that. I don't see any reason for it. (It could simply be a bug...)

Answer (score 0):

While some would consider the greatest compliment, imitation; it's highly discouraged to blatantly copy work that someone else probably spent a great deal of time working on, especially if you do not have the skill to replicate it without copying their code.

However, if your interest is purely speculative I'd suggest you look into CSS properties such as transform which would allow you to achieve a similar affect with the border property and transforming the angle of the box on hover.

Comment: I thought he was talking about the menu affect. My bad.